# Polynomial regression: Why do you need to define polynomial terms outside of lm() to avoid singularities?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, polynomials, quadratic

If you try to run a polynomial regression where `x^2` is defined in the `lm()` function, the polynomial term is dropped due to singularities. However, if we define the polynomial term outside the `lm()`, the model is fit correctly.

It seems like it should work the same both ways. **Why do we need to define the polynomial term outside the `lm()` function?**

```
x <- round(rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 10))
y <- round(x*2.5 + rnorm(100))

# Trying to define x^2 in the model, x^2 is dropped
model_wrong <- lm(y ~ x + x^2)

# Define x^2 as its own object
x2 <- x^2
model_right <- lm(y ~ x + x2)
```

Comment: Wrap it in `I` so `lm` knows where the term starts and stops: `lm(y ~ x + I(x^2))`, or just do `lm(y ~ poly(x, 2))` (with `raw = TRUE` if you want the same coefficients).

Comment: @alistaire, that was simple. Want to submit as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lm` doesn't know where the term starts and stops within the formula unless you tell it, usually by wrapping it in a function. For arbitrary calculations, you can wrap them in `I(...)`, which tells the function to use it as-is:

```r
set.seed(47)
x <- round(rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 10))
y <- round(x*2.5 + rnorm(100))

lm(y ~ x + I(x^2))
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = y ~ x + I(x^2))
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)            x       I(x^2)  
#>   2.563e-01    2.488e+00   -3.660e-06
```

Really, you can wrap `x^2` in most any function call that will return an evaluated vector that can be used in the model matrix. In some cases `cbind` can be very handy, though `c`, `identity`, or even `{...}` will work. `I` is purpose-built, though.

Alternatively, you can use the `poly` function to make both terms for you, which is very useful for higher-degree polynomials. By default, it generates orthogonal polynomials, which will make the coefficients look different:

```r
lm(y ~ poly(x, 2))
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = y ~ poly(x, 2))
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)  poly(x, 2)1  poly(x, 2)2  
#>    1.500000   243.485357    -0.004319
```

even though they will evaluate the same:

```r
new <- data.frame(x = seq(-1, 1, .5))

predict(lm(y ~ x + I(x^2)), new)
#>          1          2          3          4          5 
#> -2.2317175 -0.9876930  0.2563297  1.5003505  2.7443695

predict(lm(y ~ poly(x, 2)), new)
#>          1          2          3          4          5 
#> -2.2317175 -0.9876930  0.2563297  1.5003505  2.7443695
```

If you really want your coefficients to be the same, add `raw = TRUE`:

```r
lm(y ~ poly(x, 2, raw = TRUE))
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = y ~ poly(x, 2, raw = TRUE))
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             (Intercept)  poly(x, 2, raw = TRUE)1  poly(x, 2, raw = TRUE)2  
#>               2.563e-01                2.488e+00               -3.660e-06
```